# error:'implicit declaration of function 'nslog' is invalid at C99'

Tags: iphone

How can I fix this error: 'implicit declaration of function 'nslog' is invalid at C99'. please  tell something about this error why this is occuring.

Comment: On which code line you are facing this error? can you elaborate your question in detail?

Comment: check this :-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6704335/implicit-declaration-of-function-c99

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Upper/lower case is important in Objective-C, so the correct use is not `nslog` but [`NSLog`](http://cocoadev.com/wiki/NSLog).

Answer (score 5):

It may be because you haven’t added the foundation framework to your project.

Right click on your top level project folder, click Add -> Exisiting Frameworks and add ‘Foundation Framework’ from the list.